# Android system app does not have permission to open /dev/input

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a system app (signed with platform keys), and this app is injecting events. It is using `uinput` and tries to use `/dev/input/eventN` (where `N` is a number) as well.

If I run the code as root (i.e. with `su`), the code can obviously open `/dev/input/eventN` and can inject events in there. If the code is run from the system app, I get `permission denied` when opening `/dev/input/eventN` with `open("/dev/input/event1", O_RDWR)`. Uinput works fine, however, even in system app.

The permissions requested by the system app are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER"
                 tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER"
                 tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS"
                 tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD"
                 tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
```

For what it's worth, this system app also reads screen, and is able to do so. So it is very strange it is not able to open with r/w `/dev/input/eventN`.

You might wonder what's wrong with `uinput` if that works. The problem with `uinput` is that I have problems injecting touch events. Specifically, I can not "click" (tap). I can drag, swipe, inject keyboard events, but clicking (tapping) just does not work. It seems as if it is stuck with long press. It does not register the final event, where `ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID` is set to `0xffffffff`.

The code I'm using for "click" (tap) is:

```
// pointer down
send_event(EV_ABS, ABS_MT_SLOT, 0);
send_event(EV_ABS, ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID, m_tracking_id++ % 65535);
send_event(EV_ABS, ABS_MT_TOOL_TYPE, MT_TOOL_PEN);

// pointer coordinates
send_event(EV_ABS, ABS_MT_POSITION_X, x);
send_event(EV_ABS, ABS_MT_POSITION_Y, y);
send_event(EV_ABS, ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR, m_tracking_id % 2 ? 0x3c : 0x30);
send_event(EV_ABS, ABS_MT_PRESSURE, m_tracking_id % 2 ? 20 : 25);
send_event(EV_SYN, SYN_REPORT);

// pointer up
send_event(EV_ABS, ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID, -1);
send_event(EV_SYN, SYN_REPORT);
```